# Select dos últimos registros ordenados por 1 campo

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O objetivo é pegar os 3 últimos registros mais velhos (data mais antiga) ordenado pelo Nome. Hoje estou utilizando subselect:

```
Select * from
   (Select top 3 from TB
   order by Data desc) A
order by Nome
```

Tem algum outro jeito melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Também poderia ser um self-join. Precisaria testar as duas opções para ver qual tem a melhor performance (estou sem SQL Server no momento). De qualquer maneira, parece uma boa solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o bfavaretto comentou vc já deve estar usando a melhor opção para seus requisitos.

Note você quer:

1. Os três últimos registros.
2. Apresenta-los ordenados pelo nome.

Para o primeiro requisito você deve usar o top 3 e uma ordenação pela data para retornar os registros que vc quer. Com os três registros em mãos você ordena-os só p/ questões visuais.

Usando um self join ou uma table variable pode fazer isso mas duvido que seja + eficiente (mas um acid test é necessário para ter certeza).

A resposta do Pedro Laini não cumpre o segundo requisito pq a ordenação por data vai ter precedência no resultado apresentado.

A resposta do Guilherme Torres não é *reliable* podendo falhar caso hajam "lacunas" entre os Ids (causados por deleção por exemplo). Além disso em sua questão não foi citada correlação entre a data e o Id.

A outra única opção razoável (dependendo do contexto) seria fazer a ordenação dos três registros retornados na UI ou no Service.

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim também:

```
SELECT TOP 3 FROM TB ORDER BY Data DESC, Nome ASC
```

Comment: Isso só funciona se os 3 registros tiverem datas iguais.

Answer (score -1):

O ID é sequencial e a data crescente? Se for, daria para pegar o último id - 3.

```
Select * from TB where id >= (Select max(id) from TB) - 3  order by Nome
```

Comment: Falha se algum dos últimos registros for deletado por exemplo